# How to Classify Data In Opencv

Tags: opencv, classification

I have 130 objects.Each object is defined by 13 points(2-d points),these 13 points form data_unit. Thus there are 130 data_units. I want to classify these data_units into 4 classes. How can we do this.k-means is not possible in this scenario what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole set of classification methods based on technique called machine learning. The ones implemented in OpenCV are described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html). You can try for example [Support Vector Machines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html). Its a nice and fairly easy in use method, with some tricks to get past data that cannot be linearly separated.